# Issue on Put method for creating a tracking option - Python

Tags: python, django, python-requests, xero-api

I want to create a tracking option ((i.e) Add tracking option) under the respective tracking category, using Xero tracking category API for my organisation. But while creating data using 'put' Requests method, it is not creating.

I am using the below condition in python:

```
response = requests.put(url=url, auth=oauth, data=xml_string)
```

I want to know, what is the format for the data to be updated in the requests, for both content type xml/text and application/json.

xml_string and url, I given is below:

```
xml_string='<Option><Name>S11963</Name></Option>'
url = 'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/TrackingCategories/{Tracking_Category}/Options'
```

where `Tracking_Category='620815a2-a7c6-4b85-8b01-ffb254ab34ad'`

```
Error: <ApiException xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\r\n  <ErrorNumber>500</ErrorNumber>\r\n  <Type>UnknownErrorException</Type>\r\n  <Message>An error occurred in Xero. Check the API Status page http://status.developer.xero.com for current service status. Contact the API support team at api@xero.com for more assistance.</Message>\r\n</ApiException>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Xero API docs](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/tracking-categories#PUT), your `xml_string` might need an outer `Options` tag, something like:

```
<Options>
  <Option>
    <Name>New Option</Name>
  </Option>
</Options>
```

Comment: You may alternatively like to investigate the Xero SDK for Python so that you don't have to deal with XML by hand. https://github.com/freakboy3742/pyxero

Comment: I tried that xml_string also, but I am getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that your tracking category exists? Attempting to add options to a deleted tracking category can throw a 500 error.

Comment: Yes, that tracking category is exists. Also I tried "GET" method, I got response from that API.